# Incrementing from within for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to generate 5 unique random numbers and I have written a for loop for it:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("enter a no")
    x = int(input())
    if x not in a:
        a.append(x)
```

If `x` is not in `a`, only then `i` should be incremented. I can do this with while loop but want to know if we can do this with a for loop.

Comment: Suppose that the user stubbornly enters the same number over and over again. Then, the program never terminates. On the other hand, any reasonable implementation using a `for` loop should terminate after finitely many iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting a range into list.
Please follow the given example code.

```py
a = list()
n = 2
myrange = list(range(n)) # converting your range into list
for i in myrange:
    print("enter a no")
    x = int(input())
    if x not in a:
        a.append(x)
    else :
        # add current i again in the rangelist at starting position
        myrange.insert(0,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change how many times `for i in range()` loop runs. Changing `i` in the loop has no effect on the `range()` object.

You can use a nested loop that keeps asking until it gets a number that's not found.

```
for _ in range(5):
    while True:
        print("enter a no")
        x = int(input())
        if x not in a:
            a.append(x)
            break
```

Comment: "I can do this with while but want to know if we can do this with for" OP mentioned this in the post

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approaches:

**Option 1 :**

Using an infinite value in the range function :

```py
def to_infinity():
    index = 0
    while True:
        yield index
        index += 1

for i in to_infinity():
    print("enter a no")
    x = int(input())
    if len(a) > 5:
        break
    if x not in a:
        a.append(x)
```

**Option 2 :**

Using itertools.count:

```py
import itertools
for i in itertools.count(start=1):
    print("enter a no")
    x = int(input())
    if len(a) > 5:
        break
    if x not in a:
        a.append(x)
```

Comment: I think these will not work if the user enters just five different numbers and nothing else. Maybe check for length and break after `append` instead?

Comment: More clearly, you assume that the user will enter at least 6 numbers.

Comment: Yes you are right about that @hilberts_drinking_problem If you want make an edit and i'll accept it